# Asp .Net Micrsosft Report Viewer Issue in framework 4.5.2

Tags: asp.net

We recently migrated from framework 3.5 to framework 4.5.2. We use microsoft report viewer and .rdlc files in our reporting solution. The report viewer displays data just fine .However the inbuilt functionality Save as Excel(Export) breaks for records more than 8k. The browser just waits for 10 to 15 mins and goes to Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage. The same worked absolutely fine in framework 3.5 . We use IIS7 in windows server 2008. The report viewer version is 10.0.

Comment: You get any error message? Some code bits might be useful.

Comment: I didn't see any error messages

Answer (score 0):

got it working at last after lot of attempts. I had to explicitly call the render method and write it to response object to make it working

```
        Response.BinaryWrite(ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Render(
    "Excel", null, out mimeType, out encoding,
    out extension,
    out streamids, out warnings));
```

Comment: also had to add following config  to make it working


<trust level="Full" legacyCasModel="true"/>